# Constants (constant variables) in ALFA

Tags: authorization, abac, alfa

The OASIS Working Draft 01 for ALFA (alfa-for-xacml-v1.0-wd01) of 10 March 2015 says about constant values

> **3.15 Constant Values**
>
> Constant values can appear in the policy expressions. ALFA supports constants of type strings, integers,
> doubles and Booleans directly. Strings are quoted with single or
> double quotes. Integers consist of a number and optionally a minus
> sign. Double consists of a number with a decimal dot and optionally a
> minus sign. Booleans consist of the value true and false, without
> quotes. Other datatypes are represented using a string followed by a
> colon and the name of the datatype..

What that means is, you can use constant values like in that example (while `report` is the constant value):

```
target clause requestedType == "report"
```

But the thing is, once the ALFA files grow and you have written the constant value `report` all over, you might want to change the constant value into let's say `my.company.attributes.medicalReport`. In order to do that you have to find and replace all occurrences of the constant value.

Therefore (for the sake of avoiding redundancy) `constants` have been invented in other languages, where you define smth. like

```
const string REPORT_TYPE = "my.company.attributes.medicalReport"
```

or even more performant:

```
const integer REPORT_TYPE_ID = 3
```

or even more elegant:

```
const enum SUBJECT_TYPES { PATIENT, USER, EXAM, REPORT }
```

With those constants being defined I could write my target like:

```
target clause requestedType == REPORT_TYPE_ID
```

Does ALFA support constants or is there a way to "emulate" them (maybe a function that returns the desired value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet! It is definitely a feature we want to have. We've had similar requests so stay tuned.

Comment: What's the roadmap? When is a new version expected roughly?

Comment: What about emulating them with a function that always returns one value?